# PGR_CreateTopology maintain Source and Target ID's

Tags: pgrouting

Is there a way to set the 'source' and 'target' manually and not have it overridden in `PGR_CreateTopology()`?

I have a predefined node ID's (INODE, JNODE) in my table which is the same to a other tables in my database that I want to maintain for simplicity and consistency. This is happening:

```
GID  | INODE  | JNODE  | SOURCE  | TARGET
---- | ------ | ------ | ------- | ------
1    | 25     | 6      | 1       | 2
```

and I want this:

```
GID | INODE | JNODE | SOURCE | TARGET
--- | ----- | ----- | -----  | ------
1   | 25    | 6     | 25     | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgr_createTopology()` will always recreate the topology for the whole network. So if you want to preserve `source` and `target`, you shouldn't run this function.

It's no problem to use data, that already has network topology attributes (you may want to renumber it, because lower numbers will be better for performance). If you want to fill in the values manually, then you can do this of course, or you can write your custom function (or own tool) to do this.